# Count the number of rows a month before a date

Tags: r

I would like to add a column to my dataframe which would calculate the number of rows per park a month before each date.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
> Reaction_per_park_per_day_3

Park                            Date       Type_1_2 Coy_season AC_code  Year
  <chr>                           <date>     <chr>         <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 Airways Park                    2019-01-14 1                 1 6        2019              
2 Airways Park                    2019-01-16 0                 1 4        2019              
3 Airways Park                    2019-01-24 0                 1 4        2019              
4 Bayview                         2020-07-05 0                 3 3        2020              
5 Bayview                         2020-09-27 0                 3 3        2020
```

The resulting column would look like this:

```
Park                            Date       Type_1_2 Coy_season AC_code  Year    AC_Past_month
  <chr>                           <date>     <chr>         <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 Airways Park                    2019-01-14 1                 1 6        2019              0            
2 Airways Park                    2019-01-16 0                 1 4        2019              1
3 Airways Park                    2019-01-24 0                 1 4        2019              2
4 Bayview                         2020-07-05 0                 3 3        2020              0
5 Bayview                         2020-09-27 0                 3 3        2020              0
```

I am able to calculate the total prior number of rows using this code, but don't seem to be able to figure out how to restrict it to only the past month.

```
Reaction_per_park_per_day_3 <- Reaction_per_park_per_day_2 %>%
  group_by(Park) %>%
  mutate(Total_prior_AC = row_number() -1)
```

I tried to restrict it in time using the following code, but it did not work at all (the code does not even run).

```
Reaction_per_park_per_day_3 <- Reaction_per_park_per_day_3 %>%
  group_by(Park, Date, Type_1_2, Coy_season, AC_code, Year) %>%
  summarise(Number_4w_AC = sum(Date - weeks(4)), .groups = 'drop')
```

I would prefer dplyr solutions if possible, but I am open to any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
Reaction_per_park_per_day_3 %>%
  group_by(Park) %>%
  mutate(
    AA = sapply(Date, function(d) sum(between(as.numeric(difftime(d, Date[Date < d], units = "days")), 0, 31)))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 8
#   Park         Date       Type_1_2 Coy_season AC_code  Year AC_Past_month    AA
#   <chr>        <chr>         <int>      <int>   <int> <int>         <int> <int>
# 1 Airways Park 2019-01-14        1          1       6  2019             0     0
# 2 Airways Park 2019-01-16        0          1       4  2019             1     1
# 3 Airways Park 2019-01-24        0          1       4  2019             2     2
# 4 Bayview      2020-07-05        0          3       3  2020             0     0
# 5 Bayview      2020-09-27        0          3       3  2020             0     0
```

---

Data

```r
Reaction_per_park_per_day_3 <- structure(list(Park = c("Airways Park", "Airways Park", "Airways Park", "Bayview", "Bayview"), Date = c("2019-01-14", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-24", "2020-07-05", "2020-09-27"), Type_1_2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Coy_season = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), AC_code = c(6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L), Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L), AC_Past_month = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: That worked great, thank you!